# What is the error generated by phpcodesniffer "Tag cannot be grouped with parameter tags in a doc comment"

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

```
/**
  * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer eventobserver
  * @return void
  */
```

phpCodesniffer generate the following error for the above line.

> 41 | ERROR | Tag cannot be grouped with parameter tags in a doc comment.

What will be the reason?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

PHP_CodeSniffer isolates group of parameters in two consecutive lines in the function doc block. So adding a line between the `param` tag line and the `return` tag line will make it compatible with PHP_CodeSniffer.

```
/**
  * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer eventobserver
  *
  * @return void
  */
```

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't evident at all!

Answer (score 0):

in phpstan you must isolate blocks of code to show and debug params

```
/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param array $data comment
 * 
 * @return \App\Models\User
 */
```